# jQuery forcing click on loaded facebook video so it starts to play

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, iframe

i noticed was not an autoplay on facebook embed videos... or dont think their is so im trying to force the click so it auto play when you initially click the custom play button but think maybe im doing something wrong.

Anyone have any ideas?

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/p7v34x57/

Issue is, it loads the video but then i have to click it again to play it when its loaded...

JS:

```
function videoIframeFB() {
  var wrap = $('<iframe>');
  wrap.attr("src", "//www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=" +          $(this).attr('data-id') + "&amp;autoplay=1");
  wrap.attr("frameborder", "0");
  wrap.addClass("facebook-iframe");
  $(this).empty();
  $(this).append(wrap);
  //$(this).delay(1000).click();
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Dont remember if im honest, want me to check out the code it was for and test and see if i did? as i really dont remember lol

Comment: Yes, that would be great!